# Memory Leak with 2D Char Array

Tags: arrays, c, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to free a 2D char array but I'm getting a memory leak when I compile with `fsanitize=address` and then run the program. It doesn't seem like the code `free(innerArray)` is freeing the individual char array. Any ideas?

```
struct Item {
    char* line;
    struct Item *next;
};

void mainMethod(Item *firstArgument) {
   // Create 2d array
  int r = 5; // r gets some number 
  char **myargs = malloc((r+1)* sizeof(char *));
  myargs[0] = malloc((strlen(command)+1) * sizeof(char));
  myargs[0] = command;
  int i = 1;
  struct Item* arg = firstArgument->next;
  for ( ; i < r; i++) {
    myargs[i] = malloc(((strlen(arg->line)+1)*sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(myargs[i], arg->line);
    arg = arg->next;
  }
  myargs[i] = NULL;

  // do processing ...

  // Free 2d array
  int i = 0;
  while (i <= r) {
    char* innerArr = arr[i];
    free(innerArr);
    i++;
  }
  free(arr);
}
```

Comment: `myargs[0] = command;` Do you mean to `strcpy()` the string?

Comment: Thanks. I changed to using `strcpy` instead for `myargs[0]` and the memory leak went away.

Comment: It is not a 2d array only array of pointers. **It is not the same**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allocates a string then replaces it with the address of `command`:

```
  myargs[0] = malloc((strlen(command)+1) * sizeof(char));
  myargs[0] = command;
```

leaking the allocated memory.  If you don't need the copy just use the 2nd line, and if you want a copy either do:

```
  strcpy(myargs[0], command);
```

Or replace both lines with:

```
  myargs[0] = strdup(command);
```

As always you want to check if your allocations failed. `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` so you just leave it out.